# Android emulator lollipop stuck at the android boot screen

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

When i want to create android device manager for android lollipop 5.0 and 5.1 in visual studio 2019 16.3.5, it always stuck in the android boot screen but no issue for other versions include kitkat 4.4.

I have checked and running haxm 7.5.2 and did not enable hyper-v. all the setup are defaults and it working for all versions from kitkat 4.4 up to pie 9.0 except lollipop 5.0 and 5.1.

Hope someone can advise on this issue?

Comment: Try to expand the size, when you create the android emulator device.

Comment: @WendyZang may i know expand what size?

Anyway i found the issue. Seems like the issue is from corrupted system image. When download the system image from Visual Studio, it will stuck at the boot screen. Then i downloaded the system image from Android Studio C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images and move it to visual studio's android sdk default folder, C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the issue. Seems like the issue is from corrupted system image. When download the system image from Visual Studio, it will stuck at the boot screen. Then i downloaded the system image from Android Studio C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images and move it to visual studio's android sdk default folder, C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images, it works!